# How to add animate with respect to $ 0<t<\pi $ in the given code?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, animation, conditional

I have a two-variable function $f:=f(x,t)$. I want to plot the given conditional plot as a function of $x$ by animating the variable $t$. The given code works for particular values of $t$; how can I add animate with respect to $ 0<t<\pi $?

```
f :=  Cos[2 x] + (3 Cos[x] Sin[x])/x + (Cot[x/2] - Cos[t] Csc[x/2]) Sin[2 x] ; 

Plot[ If[ -(1/2) <= f <= 1/2 , 0 ], {x, 0, 9}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.02]]]
```

Comment: You can try `DensityPlot[f, {x, 0, 9}, {t, 0, Pi}]`

Comment: `Plot[Table[If[-(1/2) <= f <= 1/2, 0], {t, 0, π, .5}] // 
  Evaluate, {x, 0, 9}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[Automatic, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.02]]]`

Comment: This is what it [looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzGTa.png) like. The red sections are left after the `If[ ]`. Is this close to what you are expecting?

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks, I am looking for something like this. I think I was mistaken in writing the question, I meant animate instead of manipulating. Can we reproduce your plot using animating over the variable $t$?

Comment: @Syed No, I am expecting for something like the result of cvgmt in which the effect of t is illustrated through animate or manipulation.

Comment: @cvmgt : I get an empty plot when I try your code. I am on v12.2 Win7.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_, t_] := 
  Cos[2 x] + (3 Cos[x] Sin[x])/
    x + (Cot[x/2] - Cos[t] Csc[x/2]) Sin[2 x];

Animate[Plot[If[-(1/2) <= f[x, t] <= 1/2, 0, 1], {x, 0, 9}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
 , {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]